# Android: is it possible to mirror app screen on car screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, iot, android-auto, android-automotive

Is it possible to add a feature in an app where the user can mirror the app screen on the car screen monitor using Bluetooth?

**Usage:**
An Android app that retrieves some data from a server and shows this data on a map (like Google Maps) which is inside the app whose screen is mirrored on the car monitor via Bluetooth. *(assuming car monitor is running Android)*

I have seen Android Auto and Android Automotive but if sharing the app screen via Bluetooth is possible, maybe that's easier than building the app for the car.

Do you have suggestions or recommendations on how to achieve that? Things like libraries or methodologies would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: no it is not possible, you need to create an Android Auto compatible app

Comment: If you are going outside of Android Auto or Android Automotive, you will need to talk to the car manufacturer and ask them if they have other options.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So, if I wanted to build the app using Android Auto, is it possible to accomplish this usage setting? like retrieve data from some server and display it on top of a Google map. (inside the app) Thx.